# Efficient way to prevent Event Loop Blocking in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, loops, express

I'm currently in the process of creating two APIs using Express.js. Both are relatively straightforward. The first API involves a for loop that runs through 1 to 3,000,000. Meanwhile, the second API is designed to print a simple string in the console.

I have all the source codes ready and set.

```
app.get('/firstAPI', (req, res) => {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 3000000; i++) {
        console.log('First API' + i + '\n');
    }
});

app.get('/secondAPI', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Here is the Second API');
});
```

However, I've hit a snag. If I call upon the first API, it takes an extensive amount of time to execute. This lengthy process then prevents any calls to the second API, despite its simplicity. I suspect that this is due to Event Loop Blocking in node.js.

So, my question is: How can I circumvent or prevent this blockage?

Comment: Uh, don't write or run code that hogs the CPU.  Nodejs runs your Javascript in an event-driven system and uses only a single thread to run your Javascript.  If you bog down that single thread with CPU-intensive code, no other Javascript can run until your CPU-intensive code finishes.  Or if you must have code that hogs the CPU, then move that code to a workerThread or a child_process.  This is a nodejs server basic principle.  It is super efficient with its asynchronous I/O (network and disk) which do not hog the CPU.

Comment: Also, you'll probably get more meaningful help that can more meaningfully explore real alternatives or solutions if you show code for a real world problem rather than an artificial `for` loop that does nothing but hog the CPU and fill up the console on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As said above, please share an example of what you are doing because here you are just using CPU 100% which should basically never happen. Plus, you don't even respond to the request, meaning it will be hold for ever on the client side (at least until timeout)

In your code the API is already non blocking, as long as you don't load the CPU 100%. For example :

```js
app.get('/firstAPI', (req, res) => {
    console.log('First API received request');
    setTimeout(function(){
        res.end();
        console.log('First API responded to request');
    }, 5000);
});

app.get('/secondAPI', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Here is the Second API');
    res.end();
});
```

In that case, the first API takes 5 seconds to answer, but within these 5 seconds, the second API would work very fine